# Unity 3d Animation Flickering

Tags: unity

We are using 3d bus model for our game in Unity 3d.Animation works perfectly fine on Samsung s3 but some kind of texture flickering occurs on Nexus device.Please help us out how to solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: We're going to need a lot more detail.  Animation flickering in what sense?  How are you animating it?  Code samples, screenshots (or video), or anything would be helpful.